# Array of template Stack objects; syntax

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, stack

Quick question, sorry if it is stupid;

So I know that I can create a one stack with e.g.

```
myStack<int> temp_stk;
```

but I don't know the syntax to create an array filled with these.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: If you can use at least C++11, I suggest the use of the new `std::array`s instead of the old C-style arrays: `std::array<myStack<int>, 10> temp_stk;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple enough

```
myStack<int> temp_stk_array[10];
```

Comment: @Vroryn Yes, and they'll all be default initialised